# Entrywise addition of two double arrays using AVX

Tags: c++, c, arrays, avx

I need a function to entrywise add the elements of two double arrays and store the result in a third array. Currently I use (simplified)

```
void add( double* result, const double* a, const double* b, size_t size) {
    memcpy(result, a, size*sizeof(double));
    for(size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        result[i] += b[i];
    }
}
```

As far as I know the memcpy function uses AVX. In order to improve the performance I would like to also enforce AVX use for the addition. This should be one of the most basic examples for AVX, however I couldn't find any description how to do this in `C`/`C++`. I would like to avoid the use of external libraries if possible.

Comment: You will need to use intrinsics for best performance.  Even a vectorising compiler (like intel C++) is unlikely to do as good a job as specifically re-writing the code to use SIMD.

Comment: This loop (simd reduction) is perfectly and efficiently auto-vectorizable by Intel C++ compiler. I guess the same is true for any fresh GCC. For more complex ==realistic, but similar cases you may also need providng some "hints" to compilers, like using restrict keyword for function parameters or like OpenMP4.0 #pragma omp simd reduction.  Well known advantage of Compiler vectorization over intrinsics coding is portability; with intrinsics you theoretically need to rewrite and maintain your code for every next silicon and still never benefit from recent compiler optimization improvements.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll need something like this, assuming AVX-512:

```
void add( double* result, const double* a, const double* b, size_t size) 
{
    size_t i = 0;
    // Note we are doing as many blocks of 8 as we can.  If the size is not divisible by 8
    // then we will have some left over that will then be performed serially.
    // AVX-512 loop
    for( ; i < (size & ~0x7); i += 8) 
    {
        const __m512d kA8   = _mm512_load_pd( &a[i] );
        const __m512d kB8   = _mm512_load_pd( &b[i] );

        const __m512d kRes = _mm512_add_pd( kA8, kB8 );
        _mm512_stream_pd( &res[i], kRes );
    }

    // AVX loop
    for ( ; i < (size & ~0x3); i += 4 )
    {
        const __m256d kA4   = _mm256_load_pd( &a[i] );
        const __m256d kB4   = _mm256_load_pd( &b[i] );

        const __m256d kRes = _mm256_add_pd( kA4, kB4 );
        _mm256_stream_pd( &res[i], kRes );
    }

    // SSE2 loop
    for ( ; i < (size & ~0x1); i += 2 )
    {
        const __m128d kA2   = _mm_load_pd( &a[i] );
        const __m128d kB2   = _mm_load_pd( &b[i] );

        const __m128d kRes = _mm_add_pd( kA2, kB2 );
        _mm_stream_pd( &res[i], kRes );
    }

    // Serial loop
    for( ; i < size; i++ )
    {
        result[i] = a[i] + b[i];
    }
}
```

(Though be warned I've just thrown that together off the top of my head).

Something to note form the above code is that I essentially process the remaining values using the next best parallel code.  Primarily this is for illustration of the 3 possible ways you could do it parallely.  The loops will work perfectly well on their own.  For example if you can't support AVX-512 then you'd jump straight to the AVX loop.  If you can't support AVX even then if you jump straight to the SSE2 loop then you'll be using the most performant loop that your hardware can support.

For best performance your arrays should be aligned to the relevant size used in the load.  So for AVX-512 you would want 512-bit of 64 byte alignment. For AVX, 256-bit or 32 byte alignment. For SSE2 128-bit or 16 byte alignment.  If you use 64 byte alignment for all your arrays then you will always have good alignment, though you may want to go for 128 byte alignment to ease moving over to AVX-1024 when that appears ;)

Comment: Looks great, thank you very much. I'll try it first thing tomorrow.

Comment: Ok, it works. I had to use 'loadu' instead of 'load' and 'storeu' instead of 'store' because I cannot guarantee my input arrys to be aligned.Thanks again.

Comment: @Haatschii: If you need to load unaligned then you should consider aligning your data as it will be significantly faster. Equally I have modified the code to use _mm[256/512]_stream_pd as this is a faster way of writing to an array when you don't need to worry about the value being in the cache.  You *MUST* use aligned buffers with stream though!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I hoped that I could align my arrays, but unfortunaly I seems that this is not possible. The reason being that I have to add a large number of different sub-arrays of one large array. Unfortunaly I have no control on the offsets of these sub-arrys. So even if I align the large array, the sub arrys might not be aligned. Even worse 'a', 'b' and 'result' might all be diferently aligned. If you have any idea, it would be most welcome, but I fear that I have to stick to the 'loadu' variant. :/

Comment: @Haatschii: It does make life a lot more complicated. As with all such problems being able to redefine your data layout for optimal performance will make a much larger difference that you would ever expect.  If you can't, however, you can't ... that is life!  Good luck!